# Azure Active Directory webhook password expire, send notification to teams

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, webhooks

How would you send a message to teams when a users Azure AD password is expired? So far i'm looking into using incoming web hooks in channels and writing a power shell script that counts or reads a users current password expiry date and sends them a personal message when they need to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, no email notification was sent when account password is about to expire, because the only notification that O365 provides is a pop-up in the Windows Notification area of the Taskbar.

You can find the detailed powershell script to which will connect to the MSOL tenant and send password expiration notifications to all Office 365 users:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/133073-how-to-notify-office-365-users-that-passwords-will-expire

Gist is:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
$Name = $user.DisplayName
$emailaddress = $user.UserPrincipalName
$passwordSetDate = $user.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp
$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days

# Set Greeting based on Number of Days to Expiry.

# Check Number of Days to Expiry
$messageDays = $daystoexpire

if (($messageDays) -ge "1")
{
$messageDays = "in " + "$daystoexpire" + " days."
}
else
{
$messageDays = "TODAY."
}
```

You can utilise this code and store the user whose password is going to expire and then you can save the details in any DB.

Further you can have Webhook implement which will check the entry in DB for the user and send the notification in Teams.

Hope it helps.